# Android animation sequence

Tags: android

I am facing problem in getting a sequence of animation on a particular view.
I used animationset in my code and i have set the offset for each animation and the duration for the animation correctly.

somebody pls help with this.

Thanks...

Comment: Could you please add some example code and specify the problem in a bit more detail. Only with the info you provided it is very difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

To play back animations sequentially, just use the set the `android:ordering` property of the `<set>` tag to have the value `"sequentially"`.

Then, all set items will be animated in their sequence of declaration.

Answer (score -4):

For page transition use the below snippet

```
pageTransition(Context context, View view){
Animation mAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_top_to_bottom);
        mAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.ABSOLUTE);
        view.startAnimation(mAnim);
        }
```

refer the below link for more details [deVogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html)